# Creating a graph for a markov chain

Tags: graphs

I have the following problem. I want to create the following graph[image]

So far I know how to create a graph with latex. But I don't know how to insert the series points. Here is my solution. It looks similar to the above graph but without the points. Hope someone can help me

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, dsfont, bbm}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4cm,
                    semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

  \node[state]         (A)                    {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (B) [below of=A] {$A_{2}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (C) [below of=B] {$A_{1}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below of=C] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (E) [right of=A] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (F) [right of=B] {$A_{2}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (G) [right of=C] {$A_{1}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (H) [right of=D] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (I) [right of=E] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (J) [right of=F] {$A_{2}(m)$};
  \node[state]         (K) [right of=G] {$A_{1}(m)$};
  \node[state]         (L) [right of=H] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (M) [right of=J] {$A_{2}(m+1)$};


  \path (B) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (A)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (B)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (C)
        (C) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (C)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (D)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (F)
        (F) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (E)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (F)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (G)
        (G) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (G)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (H)
        (J) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (I)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (J)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (K)
        (K) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (K)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (L)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (M)
        (M) edge [loop left]  node {$\I$}                           (M);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

So that my graph looks as follows
[image]
I have defined the following commands:

```
\newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathbf{I}}
```

How can I create the three points in the graph?

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, then please accept the provided answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! This is very easy. This answer, however, is to tell you that your way of relative positioning is somewhat deprecated, it is better to employ the `positioning` library for that, and the task becomes even simpler. Likewise, `arrows` is superseded by `arrows.meta`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, dsfont, bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning}
\newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathbf{I}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=Stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                    semithick]
  \tikzset{every state/.append style={fill=red,draw=none,text=white}}

  \node[state]         (A)                    {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (B) [below=of A] {$A_{2}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (C) [below=of B] {$A_{1}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below=of C] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (F) [right=of B] {$A_{2}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (E) [above=of F] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (G) [below=of F] {$A_{1}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (H) [below=of G] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (J) [right=of F] {$A_{2}(m)$};
  \node[state]         (I) [above=of J] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (K) [below=of J] {$A_{1}(m)$};
  \node[state]         (L) [below=of K] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (M) [right=of J] {$A_{2}(m+1)$};


  \path (B) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (A)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (B)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (C)
        (C) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (C)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (D)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (F)
        (F) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (E)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (F)
            edge              node(aux) {$\QAto$}                        (G)
        (G) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (G)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (H)
        (J) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (I)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (J)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (K)
        (K) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (K)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (L)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (M)
        (M) edge [loop left]  node {$\I$}                           (M);
 \node[right=2mm of aux,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\dots};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]