# How to draw Markov chain paths with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw something like this in LateX (also with more steps):

[image]

[image]

Alternatively I could create this somewhere else and put it as a figure into latex, but I would prefer LaTeX. I think `TikZ` is a possibility, but I also heard it's hard to learn.

Comment: TikZ isn't that hard to learn, why don't you try learning it first?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. You have plenty of examples on this site on how to plot a Markov chain. This is essentially nodes and edges. [See that question for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466710/creating-a-graph-for-a-markov-chain), then come back with a specific question about a specific issue.

Comment: I think TikZ is actually quite challenging for many people to learn. The 1300-page manual is intimidating, even though the tutorials at the beginning are well-written. Many visitors to TeX.SX are beginners to LaTeX, and TikZ on top of that is a big ask. Yes—new visitors should read the intro material for this site and yes—MWEs should always be posted. But it is not helpful to beginners to tell them that things are easy just because they are easy for *you*. As the [code of conduct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/conduct) states: **If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.**

Answer (score 3):

`TikZ` can be intimidating at first, but it's worth learning. There are more efficient ways to draw your diagram once you get the basics, but at first, focus on a few basic commands: `\draw` and `\node`. This should get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} % allows ellipse nodes

\tikzset{ellnode/.style={draw, ellipse, inner sep=.5mm}} % define the style you'll use later

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5] % stretch coordinates in the x-direction. Doesn't affect text.

% draw axis
\draw[thick, ->](-4,0)--(0,0)node[above]{$t$};

% draw tick marks
\draw (-1,.2)--(-1,-.2)node[below]{$-1$};

% draw nodes
\node[ellnode] at (0,1)(n01){$s_3$}; % ellnode is the style you defined earlier
\node[ellnode] at (0,2)(n02){$s_2$}; % n02 is the name of this node for later use
\node[ellnode] at (0,3)(n03){$s_1$};
\node[ellnode] at (-1,1)(n11){$s_3$};
\node[ellnode] at (-1,2)(n12){$s_2$};
\node[ellnode] at (-1,3)(n13){$s_1$};

% draw lines
\draw[->, dashed](n11)--(n03); % draw lines using the node names from above
\draw[->, dashed](n12)--(n03);
\draw[->](n13)--(n02);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As starting point. With use of a loop for positioning of node groups. Number of nodes groups is defined by number of repetitions of loops.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,% on grid,
node distance = 7mm and 20mm,
     C/.style = {ellipse, draw, minimum width =1.2em, inner sep=1pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, ->}
                        ]
\foreach \x[count=\i] in {0,-1,-2}
{
\node (n\x1) [C] at (2*\x,0)    {$s_1$};
\node (n\x2) [C,below=of n\x1]  {$s_2$};
\node (n\x3) [C,below=of n\x2]  {$s_3$};
}
\coordinate[below right=7mm and 7mm of n03.south] (R);
\draw[<-, shorten > = -3mm] (R) node[right] {$t$} -- ++ (-8.4,0);
\foreach \x in {0,-1,...,-4}
\draw (R) ++ (2*\x-0.7,1mm) -- ++ (0,-2mm) node[below] {$\x$};
%
\draw   (n-21)   edge[dashed]   (n-12)
        (n-22)   edge           (n-11)
        (n-23)   edge           (n-11)
        (n-11)   edge           (n02)
        (n-12)   edge[dashed]   (n01)
        (n-13)   edge[dashed]   (n01);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]